# Can't hide a lightbox using .hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

This is my first time asking a question so hopefully I do it right.

I am trying to create a lightbox using jQuery/javascript.
The lightbox shows but when I want to hide it then it doesn't work.

Hopefully someone here can help me with this

```
$('.lightbox_trigger').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();



    if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) {

        $('#lightbox').show();
    }
    else{
        var lightbox =
        '<div id="lightbox">' + 
            '<p>Click to close</p>' + 
            '<div id="content">' +  
                '<p id="lightboxTxt">TEXT HERE!</p>' + 
            '</div>' +
        '</div>';

        $('body').append(lightbox);
        $('#lightbox').show();
    }

});
    $('#lightbox').on('click', function(){
        $('#lightbox').hide();
});
```

**EDIT**
Here's the html

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
>     <meta charset="UTF-8">
>     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
>     <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
>     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
>     <script src="js.js"></script>
> </head>
>
> <body>
>     <div id="logoDiv"><img src="images/logo.png"/>  </div>
> <div id="topDiv">
>   <div id="info">
>       <h1>Information om oss</h1>
>       <p>Information om sidan skrivs här</p>
>     </div><!--end info-->
>     <div id="form">
>       <form id="loginForm" name"loginForm" action="" method="POST" class="loginForm">
>           <h2>Inlogg</h2>
>           <label>
>               <span>Användarnamn: </span>
>               <input id="userName" type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Ditt användarnamn" /><br>
>           </label>
>
>           <label id="passwordLabel">              
>               <span id="passSpan">Lösenord: </span>
>               <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Ditt lösenord" /><br>
>           </label>
>
>           <label id="btnLabel">
>               <!--<input type="button" class="button" value="Registrera" id="registerBtn" name="registerBtn"/>-->
>               <a class="lightbox_trigger" href="http://www.google.se">Registrera</a>
>           </label>
>           <label>
>               <!--<input type="button" class="button" value="Logga In" id="loginBtn" name="loginBtn"/>-->
>               <a href="http://www.google.se" id="loginBtn">Logga In</a>
>
>           </label>
>       </form>
>     </div><!--end form-->
> </div><!--end topDiv-->
>
> <!--<div id="regLight" class="regLighter"></div>
> <div id="regDark" class="regDarker"></div>-->
>
>
>
>
> <div id="footerDiv">
>   <?php include ('footer.php'); ?>
> </div><!--end footerDiv-->
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: you're going to  have to show some HTML , and check to see if the HTML you wrote is different from what is actually rendered after this lightbox plugin is called

Comment: where is <.. id="lightbox"  >   , I don't see the element in your HTML

Comment: It's hiding in the JS `'<div id="lightbox">' + ` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be because your lightbox div is being loaded dynamically after the DOM load - Try this.

```
$('body').on('click', '#lightbox', function() {

  $('#lightbox').hide();

});
```

Comment: you're actually probably right , without HTML you can't 100% tell , but I deleted my answer

Comment: The .on('click' method is supposed to work on after-DOM elements, like live() used to be.

Comment: @alou - no , it only works for elements created dynamically the way it is written in this answer , not the way OP has it

Comment: @speccaN you're right, you need delegated events with on(), was just checking... sorry

Comment: When mixing with other controls such as `XPagedList`, I had to stop propagation / event bubbling: `$('.pagination').on('click', 'a', function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); $('.lightbox').css("display", "none"); });`

Answer (score 0):

If you create dynamically html you need to bind on click event after creating element

```
$('.lightbox_trigger').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();



    if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) {

        $('#lightbox').show();
    }
    else{
        var lightbox =
        '<div id="lightbox">' + 
            '<p>Click to close</p>' + 
            '<div id="content">' +  
                '<p id="lightboxTxt">TEXT HERE!</p>' + 
            '</div>' +
        '</div>';

        $('body').append(lightbox);
        $('#lightbox').show();
      // you need to  Bind on click event after creating element 
       $('#lightbox').on('click', function(){
        $('#lightbox').hide();
});
    }

});
```